# Prove that at some point the acceleration has a magnitude of at least 4 units

Tags: real-analysis, physics

A particle moves in a straight line starting from rest and finishing at rest, and covers unit distance in unit time. Prove that at some point its acceleration has a magnitude of at least 4 units. It is assumed that $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $a(t)=\frac{dv}{dt}$ are continuous functions of time.

The proof given is the following:
*If we plot $v$ against $t$, the area under the curve must be the same (1 square unit) as that of an isosceles triangle having the same base and an altitude of 2.
[image: graph]*

The slopes of the sides of the triangle are $\pm 4$. Part of the $v-t$ curve must fall outside the triangle or coincide with its sides. Thus the slope, $a$, of the curve is $\geq 4$ at some point.

I was looking for a pure analytic proof which doesn't rely on the graphical representation and intuition.

Answer (score 3):

Let $v(t)$, $a(t)$ be the velocity and acceleration at time $t\in [0,1]$. We express distance as the integral of velocity and integrate by parts, giving
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
1&=&\int_0^1 v(t)\,dt\\
&=&-\int_0^1 a(t)\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Suppose $|a(t)|<4$ for all $t$. Then
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\int_0^1 a(t)\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dt&\leq&\int_0^1 |a(t)|\left|\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right|\,dt\\
&<&\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}4\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)\,dt+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}4\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1.
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: Sorry would you mind spelling out the integration by parts in a bit more detail? I assume it's $\int_0^1 v(t)\times 1 \,\rm{dt}$, but I end up with only $-\int_0^1 a(t)t\,\rm{dt}$.

Comment: I chose $t-\frac{1}{2}$ as my anti-derivative of $dt$ (instead of just $t$)

Comment: cool! I hadn't seen that done before but it works of course!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general result:

Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, not constant and $f(a) =f(b) =0.$ Show that there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $|f'(c)| > \dfrac{4}{(b-a)^2}\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx$

Proof: The result is immediate if $f'$ is not bounded on $[a, b].$ If not then $|f'|([a, b])$ is non-empty and bounded above and hence has supremum $M >0.$ Then for all $x \in [a, b], $ $|f'(x)| \leq M.$ If $x \in [a, \frac{a+b}{2}]$ then by the mean value theorem applied to $f$ on $[a, x]$ there exists $c_x \in (a, x)$ such that
$\dfrac{f(x) -f(a)}{x-a} =f'(c_x)$ and since $f(a) =0$ and $f'$ is bounded we get $|f(x)|\leq M|x-a| = M(x-a)$

Similarly for $x \in [\frac{a+b}{2}, b]$ we obtain $|f(x)|\leq M|x-b| = M(b-x)$ 
Note that both the above relations cannot be equalities simultaneously or else the right hand derivative of $f$ at $\frac{a+b}{2}$ would be $-M$ and the left hand derivative would be $M,$ a contradiction. The rest is straightforward:

$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx &= \int_{a}^{\frac{a+b}{2}}f(x) dx+ \int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^{b}f(x)dx \\&< \int_{a}^{\frac{a+b}{2}}(x-a)dx + \int_{\frac{a+b}{2}}^{b}(b-x)dx\\&= M\dfrac{(b-a)^2}{4}
\end{align}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{4}{(b-a)^2} \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx <M$

Since $M = \sup\{|f'(x)|: x\in [a,b]\}, $ corresponding to $\varepsilon = M - \dfrac{4}{(b-a)^2} \displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx >0$ there exists $c \in [a , b]$ such that $|f'(c)| > M-\varepsilon =  \dfrac{4}{(b-a)^2}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx, $ thus completing the proof.

For the problem in question, let $f(t)$ denote the velocity function as a function of time so that $f'(t)$ denotes acceleration as a function of time. Given: $f(0)=f(1)= 0$ and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx =1.$ Then from the result above there exists $c \in [0, 1]$ such that $|f'(c)|>4.$

Note that for equality we would require the velocity function to not be differentiable at $0.5$, a case shown in the diagram posted by the OP which is a physical impossibility.

Comment: Great answer! What is the source of the theorem? I mean where did you find such a result?

Comment: Thanks. If I remember right, it was problem 121 in the continuous functions chapter in Polya and Szego's book called Problems and Theorems in Analysis

Comment: ok, that book has lots of interesting elementary and classic problems. By the way, are you a research scholar or so in Mathematics in TIFR or IMSc?